# Regex for String Parameter!

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to implement a Url Rewriting and struggling to figure out pattern matching for

> SC%3aArgument1+Argument2+%26+Argument3+Argument4.

Any help is great!!

Comment: You are looking for a pattern to match what?

Comment: Are the '+' going to be in the string. What are you trying to match and will all the characters other than the argumentX going to always be there? Are you guaranteed only 4 arguments? Can you give us a couple of different examples so we know the edge cases.

Comment: Above is passed as querystring with url.

Comment: That input is URL Encoded for "SC:Argument1 Argument2 & Argument3 Argument4.", but that probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes @Greg is right its Url encoded.. Argument1, Argument2... etc are just the name of a product. The name of product varies in length so 4 arguments are not fixed..

Comment: @Greg, Yes it is url encoded. I am trying to rewrite urls and this is passed as query string. Lot of products have SC: infront but not all so it should work for Arg1+arg2+arg3.. or Arg1. length of args is not fix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want argument1, 2, 3, and 4?

Does `SC%3a(.*?)\+(.*?)\+%26\+(.*?)\+(.*?)\.` work?

Btw, that input is URL Encoded for "SC:Argument1 Argument2 & Argument3 Argument4."

Answer (score 0):

regex in VI:

```
SC:\([^+]*\)+\([^+]*\)+&+\([^+]*\)+\([^.]*\).
```

However you should adapt it for you context - C++, perl etc.

Comment: Could you provide more samples to understand which pattern are you really considering.